Horizontal ScrollView does not scroll after adding animation to its parent component
before i animated the parent component, the scrollView was scrolling properly, but when i animated it, it stopped scrolling. i don't know what is causing the problem, please help.
i tried adding flex: 1 to the parent component but it didn't change anything
the code block is bellow.
i have also tried using a Flatlist but it didn't solve the problem

const listTab = [
  {
    category: 'All',
    id: 0
  },
  {
    category: 'Hair',
    id: 1
  },
  {
    category: 'Makeup',
    id: 2
  },
  {
    category: 'Nails',
    id: 3
  },
  {
    category: 'SkinCare',
    id: 4
  },
  {
    category: 'Fashion',
    id: 5
  },
  {
    category: 'Shoes',
    id: 6
  },
  {
    category: 'Styles',
    id: 7
  }
]


 const Home = React.memo(() => {

  const [status, requestPermission] = MediaLibrary.usePermissions();

  const { data: posts, refetch } = useAppwrite(getAllPosts);

  const { user, setUser, setIsLoggedIn } = useGlobalContext()

  const [category, setCategory] = useState()

  const [refreshing, setRefreshing] = React.useState(false);

  const [ dataList, setDataList ] = useState(posts)

  const ref = React.useRef(null);

  useScrollToTop(ref);

  const scrollY = new Animated.Value(0);
  const diffClamp = Animated.diffClamp(scrollY, 0, 145)
  const translateY = diffClamp.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0,145],
    outputRange: [0,-145],
    useNativeDriver: true,
    easing: Easing.bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1),
    duration: 200,
  })

  return (
    <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
      <Animated.View
        style={{
          transform: [
            {translateY: translateY}
          ],
          elevation: 4,
          zIndex: 100,
          flex: 1,
          
        }}
      >
        <View style={styles.headrWrapper}>
          <Header />
            <ScrollView style={styles.listTab}
              horizontal
              showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
              onScroll={(e) => {
                console.log(user.username, 'Scroll position:', e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x);
                scrollY.setValue(e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x);
              }}
              
              >
              {
                listTab.map((item) => (
                  <TouchableOpacity 
                    key={item.id}
                    style={[styles.btnTab, category === item.category && styles.btnTabActive]}
                    onPress={() => setCategoryFilter(item.category )}
                    >
                    <Text style={[styles.textTab, category === item.category && styles.textTabActive]}>{item.category}</Text>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                ))
              }
            </ScrollView>
          
        </View>
          
      </Animated.View>

      />
    </View>
  )
})


export default Home


